# Is it possible to assign a static public ip to a Docker Container?

Tags: networking, docker, lxc

I have been trying to assign one of my five public ip's to my docker container. It seems like this should be possible because of the nature of docker and its uses. I found this website that I think explains what I want to do but it no longer works since Docker went away from LXC:

http://programster.blogspot.com/2014/06/docker-run-multiple-docker-websites-on.html

I have tried making a static NAT connection with the ip that my container was using but that didn't work. The docker IP does not show up in my routers page, only the host computers ip.

My questions are:

Is it possible to assign a static public ip to a docker container, and if so how?

and

Is it possible to make a docker IP appear in my router config page, and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Possible Solution but I can't test it right now. Please let me know if this is incorrect.*

**Make virtual network interface with macvlan:**

See  https://superuser.com/questions/175475/ip-address-alias-assigned-by-dhcp

commands:

ip link add dev macvlan0 link eth0 type macvlan #macvlan0 being the name of the v-card (lol)

**Connect container to virtual network interface with pipework:**

see  https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework/#connect-a-container-to-a-local-physical-interface

commands:

pipework macvlan0 $($containerid) dhcp

Comment: Seems like extra work just to get it to 'show up' on the router page.  If it pings and responds to an IP address -- who cares if it shows up on the DHCP lease page?

Comment: I need to static Nat a few of my containers to a public IP. The IP that was assigned to one of my containers doesn't seem to work with static Nat so I think this may be a good solution. If an easier way exists please let me know! :)

Answer (score 1):

Docker 1.10 will allow you to specify a static IP-address for a container
for each network it's connected to.

(Note that, for backward compatibility, this feature is only supported for custom networks, and only if a subnet is specified)

For example;

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 mynet

docker run -d --net=mynet --ip=172.25.3.3 nginx
```

For more information see the [documentation pull request](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/19286/files)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to have a docker container use a static ip is using [pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework).

Assuming you mean acquiring a DHCP lease and showing up on your router page -- Nothing comes to mind with docker.  I don't think that is "the docker way".   It's pretty simple with nspawn if you are using a systemd based distro, FWIW.