# Assign Docker Container a Public IP

Tags: docker, docker-container

The host computer has 5 IP addresses mapped to the NIC. When I create a docker container and check what it's public IP address is using:
curl http://api.ipify.org
I find that it is always on the first IP address. I want some of the containers to use the other IP public addresses.

I have tried the process described here:
https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/ips-for-all-the-things/

but after starting the container this way, it seems to have no network access and cannot even ping to any outside host.

I have also tried the first answer given here:
[Is it possible to assign a static public ip to a Docker Container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516284/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-static-public-ip-to-a-docker-container)

but that also causes the container to not have any outgoing network access.

My docker --version gives: 17.09.1-ce

What is the right procedure to setup a Docker container and assign it a public IP address that is already mapped to the host?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use macvlan driver rather than bridge. do as following

First delete the network you create
 then create new custom network using following command

> > docker network create --driver=macvlan --subnet=142.5.162.178/29
> >     --gateway=142.5.162.177 custom_net "-o parent=eth0
> >
> > docker run -itd --net=custom_net --name cont1 --ip=142.5.162.178 --dns=8.8.8.8 alpine
> >
> > docker exec -it cont1 sh
> >
> > ping google.com

Hope this will work.